# Type conversion error with async programming

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

I have a method that looks like this:

```
public virtual async Task<IList<User>> GetAll()
{
    return this.db.Users.Where(model => model.CompanyId.Equals(this.companyId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToListAsync();
}
```

when I try to compile my code I get an error stating:

> Error 10  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  C:\Users\Jaymie\Documents\GitHub\Skipstone\Skipstone.Web\Repositories\UserRepository.cs 70  20  Skipstone.Web

Yet directly under it I have this method:

```
public Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
{
    return this.db.Users.Where(model => model.Id.Equals(userId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

which works fine.

I think I can't see the wood for the trees so need someone else's eyes to help me out :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `ToListAsync` methods return a `Task<List<T>>` object, which translate to a `Task<List<User>>` object in your case, but your method's return type is `Task<IList<User>>`.

The issue here is that covariance is not supported for `T` in `Task<T>`.

So, either you change the method's return type to `Task<List<User>>`, or you write the code to make the conversion yourself:

```
return this.db.Users
    .Where(model => model.Id.Equals(userId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .ToListAsync()
    .ContinueWith<IList<User>>(t => t.Result, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
```

Comment: Ah I see :) I thought it was something simple :D

Comment: @r3plica: I added the `ExecuteSynchronously` argument to the continuation in order to reduce the overhead of the continuation task.

Comment: @JeanHominal Could you please explain your reasons for adding ExecuteSynchronously? I am new to the whole sync/async programming and trying to make sense of it. It appears to me that what yo have done is turn a async method into a sync method, which seems strange. Even if you have gained performance, you have lost asynchonisity.

Comment: @MikeDymond: No, I did not turn an async method into a synchronous method. What happens is that there are two operations taking place here: first, the creation of the list, and second, the unpacking of the list from the original `Task<List<User>>` object. What `ExecuteSynchronously` does is specify that the second task execute synchronously relative to the first task - if the first task executes asynchronously, then the whole process still runs asynchronously. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions.aspx) for more details.

Comment: @JeanHominal Thank you that is really helpful. Wish I could upvote a comment :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using async keyword, then you need use await keyword return original type .

```
public virtual async Task<IList<User>> GetAll()
{
    return await this.db.Users.Where(model =>
         model.CompanyId.Equals(this.companyId, 
              StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);;
}
```

Or without async you need to specify type Task as you did in the second sample that is working.

Comment: Your code does not compile. As stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx), "the return type of an async method can be `Task<TResult>`, `Task` or `void`".

Comment: yes, thank you. i missed it. it's correct, that it should have Task as result type.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Actually, the `async` and `await` is used in order to upcast the task's result from `List<User>` to `IList<User>`.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov: Also, you should follow-up your call to `ToListAsync()` with [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait.aspx) - the reason for that is that, when using `await` on a `Task` object, you should always use `ConfigureAwait(false)` if you do not care about how the rest of your method is synchronized. (The reason is explained on [Stephen Cleary's blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).)

Comment: Thanks @JeanHominal for the comment, I didn't know about it. Very interesting blog post!