# Cannot convert Task<List<TEntity>> to Task<IList<TEntity>>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, covariance, contravariance

I'm writing a small wrapper method around EF Core `DbSet`. I have the following method:

```
public Task<IList<TEntity>> GetAsync(Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> getFunction)
{
    if (getFunction == null)
    {
        Task.FromResult(new List<TEntity>());
    }
    return getFunction(_dbSet).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}
```

The class is generic as you can see and _dbSet is an instance of concrete `DbSet` from the context. It does not matter that much for the question, however.
For the code I get the below error:

> [CS0029] Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'
>   to
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'

If I change return value to `Task<List<TEntity>>` there is no error.
Does anyone have an idea why it cannot convert it? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type conversion error with async programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950908/type-conversion-error-with-async-programming)

Comment: @Sinatr You could propose edit and I would be glad to accept it :) Thank you anyway

Comment: `Task` is not an interface and hence [doesn't support covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2733346/4137916). A `Task<List<...>>` can only yield a `List<...>` and not any class implementing `IList<...>`. It would conceivably be useful to do so, but isn't considered useful enough to actually implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way in my opinion is to await the task. So it will work with minimum changes:

```
public async Task<IList<TEntity>> GetAsync(Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> 
getFunction)
{
    if (getFunction == null)
    {
        return new List<TEntity>();
    }
    return await getFunction(_dbSet).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}
```