# Overriding GetRolesAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

What I'd like to do is

```
public override Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    return Context.UserOrganisationRole
        .Where(z => z.UserId == user.Id)
        .GroupBy(z => new { z.RoleId, z.Role })
        .Select(z => z.Key.Role.Name + "-" + string.Join(",", z.OrderBy(z => z.OrganisationId).Select(z => z.OrganisationId)))
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

But that doesn't work because `Task<List<string>>` can't be cast to `Task<IList<string>>`.

Therefore I tried adding

```
.ContinueWith<IList<string>>(t => t.Result, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
```

from [Type conversion error with async programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20950908/type-conversion-error-with-async-programming)
which compiles but doesn't run because:

> The LINQ expression <...> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),...

Which I think means it's trying to do too much on the database. Fine. However, having added the requested `IEnumerable` it now appears to be impossible to get the required `Task<IList<string>>` to return

```
return Context.UserOrganisationRole
    .Where(z => z.UserId == user.Id)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(z => new { z.RoleId, z.Role })
    .Select(z => z.Key.Role.Name + "-" + string.Join(",", z.OrderBy(z => z.OrganisationId).Select(z => z.OrganisationId)))
```

I.e., write this for me!

```
public Task<IList<string>> ListToTaskIList (IList<string> list)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just `await` the result of the query:

```
public async override Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(ApplicationUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    return await Context.UserOrganisationRole
        .Where(z => z.UserId == user.Id)
        .GroupBy(z => new { z.RoleId, z.Role })
        .Select(z => z.Key.Role.Name + "-" + string.Join(",", z.OrderBy(z => z.OrganisationId).Select(z => z.OrganisationId)))
        .ToListAsync();
}
```